# Open Links in an iframe in a new tab

Tags: javascript, html, css, excel

I have converted an excel file to an .htm file.
In the excel file are links.
I have embedded the .htm file in my website
These links should be open in a new tab and not in the iframe.

How can I do this?
target="_blank" didn't work.

```
<iframe src="website.htm" style="border:none;" width="100%" height="300">
</iframe>
```

This also not worked:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<iframe src="website.htm" style="border:none;" width="100%" height="300">
</iframe>
<script>
$('iframe a').attr('target', '_blank');
</script>
```

Comment: `iframeElement.contentWindow.document` is JavaScript from your page containing the iframe to access the iframe document. Program as usual.

Comment: @PHPglue what do you want to say?What should I do different?

Comment: `$('iframe').eq(0).contents()` will give you the iframe document, with jQuery. I don't think iframe links will open in anything except the iframe window, so you will have to do that from the parent window, programmatically, if you want to use your iframe design.

Comment: Can you describe, how I can do it?

Comment: The same way you do jQuery on the parent page. You have to as least understand jQuery to use it. I personally recommend that you separate data from the DOM *(Document Object Model)*. In other words you should just have a program on the Server that parses your excel sheet, and outputs that to JSON, for use in your HTML. Use AJAX to get data off the Server. Rarely use iframes.

Comment: The iframe contents will be protected by cross-domain restrictions. This may be very frustrating because you generally cannot reach into the iframe from outside, but it is an important security feature. You said you converted the Excel file to html yourself, so perhaps you have the html code available on your server? If so, you could load it with one of these techniques: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file. If not, you probably need to fetch it as with an XMLHttpRequest and either CORS or (god forbid?) web-scraping.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
<iframe src="website.htm" style="border:none;" target="_top" width="100%" height="300">
</iframe>
```

Using jQuery:

```
$('iframe a').attr('target', '_blank');
```

Comment: target="_parent" ?? dId you try ?

Comment: With jQuery it didnt worked, too. Look at my code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like below:

```
var linkList = [iframeElement].contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0; i < linkList.length; i++) {
    linkList[i].target = "_blank";
}
```

Comment: The iframe's src is not the same domain with the parent window? It's a question about cross domain.So you must modify the links in the iframe page and add "target='_blank'" to the links

Comment: No, the iframe src is not the same as the parent window

Comment: Ok, you can edit the iframe's inner page,  and there's no any other way because the ifame acrosses origion from current page (Sorry, I'm not good at english), you can also search the answers via keywords : "iframe cross domain"